# how to remove class of a specific element inside an element

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function myfunction() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll("#ol li"),
    array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    array.push(items[i].innerHTML);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<ol id="ol">
  <li class="li">
    <span class="x">hello</span>
    <span class="xx">testing</span>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <span class="x">hello2</span>
    <span class="xx">testing2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <span class="x">hello3</span>
    <span class="xx">testing4</span>
  </li </ol>

  <div id="content"></div>

  <button onclick="myfunction()">click</button>
```

When I click on one of the lists, the code will put the innerHTML of the list that I clicked into a div, but I also want to remove the class of the spans in the list that is inside the div

How can I do this?

ive tried this but it doesnt work

```js
 function myfunction() {
      let items = document.querySelectorAll("#ol li"),
        array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        array.push(items[i].innerHTML);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].onclick = function() {
         document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.innerHTML;

        const spanInsideDiv = document.querySelector("#content .li .x")
        for (var i = 0; i < spanInsideDiv.length; i++) {
               spanInsideDiv[i].classList.remove('li');
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: _"the span with class "x" inside the list that is inside the div when i click on one of the lists"_ this is hard to understand. Please may you make it clearer?

Comment: sorry i just edited it i hope you understand it now

Comment: @coder not clear still.

Comment: Please present code examples that at least do what you say they should, in the first place. The one currently given here doesn’t, because `document.getElementById.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;` simply makes no sense.

Comment: @decpk ok so when i click on a list, the #content div will have a list with some spans in it and i want to remove the class of all spans that is inside the #content div

Comment: @CBroe oops sorry i didnt notice that, i already changed it

Comment: `spanInsideDiv[i].classList.remove('li');` – none of the span elements has the class `li`, so you are currently trying to “remove” something here, that did not even exist in the first place.

Comment: Your whole myFunction could basically be **one** line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your simply copying all the innerHTML to the target `<div>`. After this happened we can get a **HTMLCollection** - more or less an array - of all the `<span>` elements inside using:

```
document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("span");
```

Now we can simply loop over the collection and remove all the css classes by calling `removeAttribute("class")` on each one. This will remove any css class while keeping your original spans intact.

Here's an example:

```js
function myfunction() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll("#ol li"),
    array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    array.push(items[i].innerHTML);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = function() {

      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
      let span = document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("span");

      for (var a = 0; a < span.length; a++) {
        span[a].removeAttribute("class");
      }
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<ol id="ol">
  <li class="li">
    <span class="x">hello</span>
    <span class="xx">testing</span>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <span class="x">hello2</span>
    <span class="xx">testing2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <span class="x">hello3</span>
    <span class="xx">testing4</span>
  </li>
</ol>

<div id="content"></div>

<button onclick="myfunction()">click</button>
```

Comment: No problem - glad I could help! By the way, if you think this is the right answer please consider accepting it using the 'tick' button.